# Add +1 every time a program has run?

Tags: powershell

I recently wanted to improve my code by cleaning it up a bit. In my simple copy and paste program, I want to create a log file every time after the program ran. The problem is with naming the text file: I don’t want to overwrite any log-files and therefore give the file a unique name. Right now it looks like this:
`start-transcript - Path $Sourcefolder\log-$logname_$logH.$logM.$logS`

Basically it creates a log file based on the time you ran the program and a unique name will be given (I had to use hours, minutes and seconds in a seperate function otherwise special characters would be used but that’s not the problem)

The result would look like this:
`log-08.11.202114.47.56`

Not really that great.
My solution to the problem would be adding the variable $i and adding +1 every time the program run.
But if I try to do so, the value will automatically reset to 0 after it’s done.

My question, is there a way to implement this or is there another way?

(Sorry if bad format, currently on mobile)

Comment: I am not going to mark this as an answer since I am very junior here and not sure what I am about to offer will help. If it does let me know and I will make this an answer. I wrote a function that does what you need for myself take a look and maybe someone else will give you a better answer. <https://github.com/dcazman/MRNAP>. PS: I am not a pro programmer but I use this function above many times a day.

Comment: Maybe you can read the last file name in the output folder and add +1 to it.

Comment: Why not use `(Get-Date).Ticks` or use a guid?

Comment: It is better to derive the next sequence number by determining the highest sequence number among the existing log file names adding 1 to that. The linked duplicate shows how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not put an ISO8601-like timestamp in the log filename. Is granularity greater than one (1) second needed?

```
PS C:\> $LogFilename = 'log-' + (Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMddTHHmmss') + '.log'
PS C:\> $LogFilename
log-20211108T083105.log
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use below reusable helper function to always ensure a unique filename:

```
function Get-UniqueFileName {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true, Mandatory = $true, Position = 0)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path        # the suggested full path and filename
    )

    $directory = [System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($Path)
    $baseName  = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($Path)
    $extension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($Path)    # this includes the dot
    # get an array of all files with the same extension currently in the directory
    $allFiles  = @(Get-ChildItem $directory -File -Filter "$baseName*$extension" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)

    # construct the possible new file name (just the name, not the full path and name)
    $newFile = $baseName + $extension
    $seed = 1
    while ($allFiles -contains $newFile) {
        # add the seed value between brackets. (you can ofcourse leave them out if you like)
        $newFile = "{0}({1}){2}" -f $baseName, $seed, $extension
        $seed++
    }
    # return the full path and filename
    return Join-Path -Path $directory -ChildPath $newFile
}
```

In your case you can then do:

```
$Sourcefolder = 'D:\Test'
$logFile = Join-Path -Path $Sourcefolder -ChildPath ('{0:yyyyMMdd}.log' -f (Get-Date)) | Get-UniqueFileName
```

Example:

If a file called `D:\Test\20211108.log` already exists in your source folder, this will return a new filename `D:\Test\20211108(1).log`. The next one will be `D:\Test\20211108(2).log` etc.

---

or, as already commented, you can use the DateTime [Ticks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.ticks) property te be pretty sure the filename will be unique:

```
$logFile = Join-Path -Path $Sourcefolder -ChildPath ('{0}.log' -f (Get-Date).Ticks)
```

Returns `D:\Test\637719832681865978.log`